# Dual GFX cards, one stops working

Tags: windows-7, graphics-card, device-manager

I have a workstation with 2 gfx cards which display three monitors. One gfx card works with two monitor and works perfectly, the other gfx card which only display on one monitor will fail to work.

When it fails, the monitor goes black and if you go to Device Manager both cards are visible except for the malfunctioning card has a yellow icon and it states windows has stopped it because of a problem. I have reinstalled, updated all the drivers for this gfx card but the problem will still persist. I can fix and get the gfx card working again IF I uninstall the device from Device Manager and re-scan for hardware changes (no reboots neccesary). Doing  a straight reboot will not fix the device manager error alone, I have to uninstall the device and rescan.

The device will work properly for a few hours (maybe a day) with several reboots too, and then windows will stop the device again. There are no events in the window logs. I did a checkdisk repair, found no problems.

I guess the question would be... is it fixable without replacing gfx card, and if so how?

Comment: OK, sounds like the graphics adapter is probably broken. What's your question?

Comment: i guess the question would be... is it fixable without replacing gfx card, and if so how?

Comment: Does the problem persist if you only use the potentially broken graphics card? Does it persist if you swap the cards around? (If it moved to the 'other card' then the problem might be the connector, traces on the motherboard or something else, but probably not the graphics card).